# Java: How to declare a List using a Class object as parameter?

Tags: java

I'm looking to invoke by reflection a method that returns `List<X>`. However, I do not have the class definition for X, so I can only get the type by reflection. What's the proper syntax for declaring `List<X>`, where X is a Class object?

Comment: It's [`List<Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Actually, it’s `List<?>` rather than `List<Object>` as otherwise you could add *anything* into the `List`. It depends on the context whether this is an issue. If the method returns a reference to a shared `List` it *is* an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `List<Object>`, this will work for any object.

Comment: @lairtech Just keep in mind that you will be unable to know easily from which class each instance in the list is. This can get very annoying later on. I suggest you rethink your approach, maybe use a base interface or class for the objects held in the `List` instead of `Object`.